# Keep JSON Request in English using FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to implement a multi-language application.  I want the calendar to be multi-language, but I want to keep the JSON request in English.  When I switch languages the JSON request is sent in the language I switched to, an example is shown below:

English:

```
http://localhost:8000/Application/calendarApi/?start=2015-06-28&end=2015-08-09
```

Switch to Arabic:

```
   http://localhost:8000/Application/calendarApi/?start=%D9%A2%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A5-%D9%A0%D9%A6-%D9%A2%D9%A7&end=%D9%A2%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A5-%D9%A0%D9%A8-%D9%A0%D9%A8
```

I want to keep all requests in English, but have different languages for the calendar view.  Here is the relevant code for the application:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentLangCode = "en";

    $.each($.fullCalendar.langs, function(langCode) {
        $('#lang-selector').append(
            $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', langCode)
                .prop('selected', langCode == currentLangCode)
                .text(langCode)
        );
    });

    // rerender the calendar when the selected option changes
    $('#lang-selector').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            currentLangCode = this.value;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
            renderCalendar();
        }
    });

    function renderCalendar() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center:'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek'
            },
            lang: currentLangCode,
            eventLimit:true,
            eventSources: {
                url: "getEvents/",
                cache: true
            },
            lazyFetching:true,
            dayClick: function() { alert($("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start);}

        });
    }

    renderCalendar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One hack to accomplish this is to use only English numerals (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0).  The majority of languages use these numerals, and they are for the most part internationally understood.  If you are using `lang-all.js` (http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.2/lang-all.js), what you want to do is replace all numerals with English numerals.  This can be done in sublime by doing the following:

1. Open the Replace
2. Select regex
3. Type this into find:

   ```
   var c=\{1\:(.)(.)(.),2\:(.)(.)(.),3\:(.)(.)(.),4\:(.)(.)(.),5\:(.)(.)(.),6\:(.)(.)(.),7\:(.)(.)(.),8\:(.)(.)(.),9\:(.)(.)(.),0\:(.)(.)(.)\}
   ```
4. And this into replace:

   ```
   var c={1:"1",2:"2",3:"3",4:"4",5:"5",6:"6",7:"7",8:"8",9:"9",0:"0"}
   ```

For each language that has numerals differing from [0-9] and array with the following format is used to represent that array:

```
var c={1:"<1 in that language>", 2:"<2 in that language>" ...
```

So what the regex does is find all occurrences of that and replace it with the [0-9] numerals instead.